# How to expand DIV to fit set area in set position, without re-positioning it?

Tags: html, css, animation, position

The best way I can explain my question is by the picture I posted below. Basically when you increase the number of the width of an object it expands to the right(see figure 1), I know you can make it expand to the left by adding some changes to the css positioning, but I need my div to expand a little to the left and a little to the right to be able to take up a certain amount of space at a certain position.(See figure 2 below)
**What does happen (AKA the closest I can get):**

**### Figure 1:**

 [image: What does happen]

**What I want to happen (fill the whole area):**


**### Figure 2:**


[image: What I want to happen]

so basically I want to know how I can achieve what is happening in figure 2

Comment: My goal is to do this without re-positioning the square, because I want it to look like it is fitting to the given area.

Comment: try using height:100%; width 100%; margin:0 auto:

Comment: I tried that but it just really messed it up. Literally every element on the screen vanished when I clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 .div {
    width: someWidth;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Definitely got me closer but still does't solve my problem. The DIV isn't exactly in the center or else that would work great.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved quite easy using `flexbox`.

Use `align-items: flex-end;` `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;`in your parent element. Then define the child dimensions.

`align-items: flex-end;` : To vertically position the element at the end in the cross axis.

`justify-content: center;` : To horizontally center the element in the main axis.

---

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/rmwcjkca/)**

---

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  border: .5em dashed black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.flex-item {
  flex-basis: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's another demo for you to see how this behaves if you change the child element dimensions. *(Click the blue square to toggle dimension change).*

---

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/xeLxpo27/)**

---

```js
$(".flex-item").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("flex-item--big");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  border: .5em dashed black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.flex-item {
  flex-basis: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  transition: flex-basis 300ms linear, height 300ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-item--big {
  flex-basis: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

---

### **EDIT 2:**

After some specifications mentioned in the comments, here's what can be done.

> To tweak "margin" between flex-items you would need to make this a
>   little bit more complex, wrapping each item in a container and adding
>   padding, which is not in the scope of the following demo.

---

*Notes & Recommendations:*

- Try to avoid width and height changes in your elements, you should stick to `transform` and `opacity` in transitions and animations.
- Try to make your transitions faster, something between 300ms and 500ms

---

### **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/okay483L/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
function panels() {
  /* jQuery Objects */
  var $panelsContainer = $(".panels-container"),
    $panel = $(".panel"),

    /* Strings of Classes used */
    cHasPanelOpened = "has-panel-opened",
    cHoverEffect = "panel-hover-effect",
    cOpened = "opened",
    cLastClicked = "last-clicked",
    cFaded = "faded";

  /* Panel click event listener */
  $panel.on("click", function() {
    $panelsContainer
      .toggleClass(cHasPanelOpened);

    $(this)
      .toggleClass([cHoverEffect, cOpened].join(" "))
      .addClass(cLastClicked);

    $panel.not(this)
      .toggleClass(cFaded)
      .removeClass(cLastClicked);
  });
}

$(document).ready(panels);
```

```css
body {
  /* DEMO illustration purposes only */
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: .5em dotted darkorange;
  height: 100vh;
  /* DEMO illustration purposes only */
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*

    Panels Container

*/

.panels-container {
  display: flex;
  //width: 460px;
  //height: 290px;

  /* DEMO illustration purposes only */
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(.9);
  /* DEMO illustration purposes only */
}
/*

    Panel Sections

*/

.panel__section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.panel__section--media {
  flex-basis: 66%;
}
.panel__section--download {
  flex-basis: 34%;
}
/*

    Panel

*/

.panel {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 300ms, opacity 500ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel--blue {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  background-image: url('https://cdn2.scratch.mit.edu/get_image/user/15016755_60x60.png?v=1465352804.66');
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.panel--red,
.panel--yellow {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.panel--red {
  background: url('http://iconshow.me/media/images/Application/Modern-Flat-style-Icons/png/512/Video.png') #F44336 no-repeat center;
  background-size: 120px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.panel--yellow {
  background: url('https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/10731543_602219616549530_1911663388_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=ODQxODcxMTQxNDcxOTE1NzQw.2') #FFEB3B no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.panel--green {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698860-icon-129-cloud-download-128.png') #4CAF50 no-repeat center;
  transform-origin: center right;
}
/*

    Handle each panel when opened

*/

.panel--blue.opened {
  transform: scale(calc(1/.66), 2);
}
.panel--green.opened {
  transform: scaleX(calc(1/.34));
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.panel--red.opened {
  transform: scale(calc(1/.33), 2);
}
.panel--yellow.opened {
  transform: scale(calc(1/.33), 2);
}
/*

     Styling Helpers
    
*/

.faded {
  opacity: 0;
}
.opened {
  outline: 0;
}
.last-clicked {
  z-index: 1;
}
.panel-hover-effect:hover {
  transform: skewY(3deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Panel Section Begin -->
<section class="panels-container">
  <section class="panel__section panel__section--media">
    <div class="panel panel--blue panel-hover-effect"></div>
    <div class="panel panel--red panel-hover-effect"></div>
    <div class="panel panel--yellow panel-hover-effect"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="panel__section panel__section--download">
    <div class="panel panel--green panel-hover-effect"></div>
  </section>
</section>
<!-- Panel Section End -->
```

---

You can read more about flexbox **[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

Comment: I am a little confused. So flexbox will allow my div to fit to the container it is in, or in the case of the code you provided, the dotted bordered box?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want the blue element to be positioned there in relation to its container, even if you change the blue element  dimensions.

Comment: Not exactly, basically I want the blue element to expand to the exact shape and size of the container without having to move the position of the the element. Basically you can imagine each side of the blue element (except the bottom because it is already in line with the container) expanding at different rates, to eventually reach the size of the container.

Comment: Oh okay, so basically a similar behavior as the second demo I provided but filling the whole container?

Comment: Yep exactly. I didn't even see that fiddle until now, but that is a pretty good representation except it needs to be able to fill the whole box, even if it isn't exactly in the center. Here is the project I am occurring this problem on http://codepen.io/JoshuaHurlburt/pen/NAQjaQ . I am trying to find a way to expand that red box to the area of all the panels, which is 460(h) x 290(w)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want, but will that work even if the box is more to the side? I have to sign off for the night cause I'm leaving work. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I added another demo, but I don't know if using flexbox will be ideal now. The property you are looking for in your original question is `transform-origin.`  Here's more [**info**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform-origin/).